# How to find object in arraylist with the Contains method

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, contains

Hi I have an array class that hold a bank data:
account number, balance, account type, and status.
the array is built with a constructor:

```
Bank.accounts.add(new Account(this.accNumber, this.type, this.balance, this.status));
```

and when I try to find a number (on a different method), it doesn't find it.

The method gets an input of a bank number account, and then compares it to the accounts array list. If found, a console interface is opened, however it never find the account number.
I've tried scanner integer, string to integer, and using the contains method from inside the method or as a standalone method(like example below) with no success.

The method is:

```
public void accountActions() {

    System.out.println("Enter number of account for more info");
    Boolean isFinished = false;
    while (!isFinished) {
        try {

            String scan = input.nextLine();
            Bank.number = Integer.parseInt(scan);
            isFinished = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter again\n------------------------------");
            isFinished = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter again\n------------------------------");
            isFinished = false;
        }
    }
    if (checkAccountNumber(number) == true) {
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("=                                   =");
        System.out.println("=   Enter command number            =");
        System.out.println("=                                   =");
        System.out.println("=   1. Withdraw money               =");
        System.out.println("=   2. Deposit                      =");
        System.out.println("=   3. Total money in all accounts  =");
        System.out.println("=                                   =");
        System.out.println("=====================================");

    } else {
        System.out.println(
                "No account was found by that number, would you like to try again?\n(((Yes/No)))\n---------------");
        yesNo("accountActions");
    }
}
```

And the standalone method is:

```
public boolean checkAccountNumber(int a) {
    boolean check = false;
    if (Bank.accounts.contains(a)) {
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid raw types in your collection.

Comment: Note that it might be a better design to model `Bank.accounts` data structure as a hash table from account number to `Account`. Then you can simply look up an account number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an Account with an AccountNumber. Instead of this, you should do this.

```
public boolean checkAccountNumber(int a) {

    for (Account account of Bank.accounts){
        if (account.accNumber.equals(a)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, you have to override 'equals(...)' and 'hashCode()' methods in the Account class

Comment: It's no necessary because AccountNumber are integers, and Mcaulish is trying to find Accounts by AccountsNumber.

Comment: Worked for me! I've used equals instead of contains since its integer. I'm a beginer and didnt work the difference between object and primitive with what ive been looking for. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an `int`, while `Bank.accounts` is a `List` of `Account` objects, your code is not working.

You can use `Stream.anyMatch` to check for the presence of an `Account` having the passed in account number.

The main advantage of `anyMatch` over a loop is, it is short circuiting, it won't evaluate all the elements of the stream it will return on first match.

As per the **[Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)** of `anyMatch`:

> May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for
>   determining the result.

Example code:

```
class Bank {
    static List<Account> accounts;
    ...
}
public boolean checkAccountNumber(int a) {
    return Bank.accounts.stream().anyMatch(acc -> acc.accNumber.equals(a)); 
}
```

You could have avoided this issue by **not** using `Raw` types. Generify your `Bank.accounts` List to `List<Account>`, so you can catch this kind of errors at compile time.